# modify bootstrap 3 input-addon height possible?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it correct that the input-addon height cannot be manipulated?

```
<span class="input-group-addon" style="height: 25px;">%</span>
```

The code above has no effect whatsoever.

Can somebody confirm?

Answer (score 0):

My quick solution is to set a 0px top margin in the input-group-add-on class.